# Differential equations modelling rats factor of $e$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given this question by a friend and I could not solve it.

a perfect environment, the population of Norway rat that breeds on the MIT campus increases by a factor of $e$ each year. Model this natural growth by a differential equation.
What is the growth rate k?

I know how to solve these questions normally. What I don’t get is the part about factor of $e$. I know if it says it was proportional to the population number , I could find the de and solve it easily but what does a factor of $e$ even mean? Is it just a fancy way to say the number of rats can be modeled by a function of $e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the population grows by a factor of $e$ each year then the population at time $t$ is given by
$$x(t) = x_0e^t$$

Where $x_0$ is the initial population and $t$ is measured in years. Therefor
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = k x, \quad x(0) = x_0$$

is your equation, with $k=1$